# Adjusting Table Filter Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to adjust some javascript that currently allows a user to enter text into an input, then it would hide all rows that do not contain that text. Right now it only checks the first column, but I would like it to check columns 1 and 2:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Country</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Size</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe Smith</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>Medium</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Jane Doe</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Small</td>
  </tr>
</table>

So in the simple example below, you could type either Jane or Germany to have that row show filter.
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
   var found = false;
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];
      if (td) {
          txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              found = true;
              break;
          }
       }
    }
    if (found) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

Create an inner loop over the columns, checking each columns. When text is found, break the loop. After loop, check found property, set route display.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! But is there any way to exclude other columns? Say I don't want column 3 to respond to the filter input.

Comment: Well of course, you can modify the `for` to only loop the first 2, or right after the `for` line you can check the column index or whatever, and use `continue` to continue the `for`. All quite basic coding, I suggest you check our the W3C JavaScript examples for this as well. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp